# Jquery for radio button effect in divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm realy new to css and jquery and I need help for my project.

I have 3 buttons: disadvantage - average - advantage and I need to make this buttons to work like radio buttons so if I click on disadvantage this button change background color and other butons lose colors if was clicked on him. and disadvantage button get red backrground color.

- If I click on average button, this button must get yellow color and other lose color if was clicked on him before

-If I click on average button this button must get green background color and other buttons to lose color. so like radio buttons

BUt I try to do that based on #ID's

```
$('#price_quality_adv').css('background-color','#C90');
            $('#reliability_adv').css('background-color','#C90');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EC44Z/5/

please help. sorry for my english
THANKS!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EC44Z/10/ without JS code for beter understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a scope issue of some kind, not sure if it is exclusive to jsFiddle environment. When I make this change, it is fixed (for the advantage button at least)

```
setQuality = function(qulaity, type_rating, name)
```

### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EC44Z/8/

There are still some other issues however, the code is a little complex. It is better to do something like...

### HTML

```
<a href="#" id="button_advantage" class="button">advantage</a>
```

### CSS

```
.button{ /* styles for all buttons */ }
.selected{ /* styles for selected button */ }
```

### JS (jQuery)

```
$("#button_advantage").on('click',function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected')
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected')
})
```

### Summary

The code should be separated, so it is easier to maintain, works well in various environments, and gets good search ranking etc...

HTML is for content, and should be marked up as such, with appropriate classes to group similar items, and unique id for relevant elements.

CSS is for style, and all styles should be kept together there where possible.

JS is for dynamic functionality, so in this case, adding a class, so that the style changes.

Comment: no, function work for all developed code in my project, this is just part of code and I need to select ID on click and on that change color...

Comment: ok, i was try that but dont work becouse i need to implement this in my setQuality function

Comment: Billy provided you with the `.click()` function: http://api.jquery.com/click/
This is worth looking into.

Comment: Here is the basic idea, CSS needs tweaking. I simplified HTML, only really using the ID and CLASS attributes, so the elements can be identified for styling and function, but not mixed with HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/EC44Z/11/

Comment: I have an idea. How to write my own function to do what I want and they just call that function in function setQuality. Can you please help me with that? THANKS!

Comment: I added some details of how you can call another function when handling the clicks: http://jsfiddle.net/EC44Z/13/